# Global @Resource format priority

Tags: grails

Is it possible to define the priority of the Resource format (json, xml) globally in config.groovy instead of specifying on each Resource?  For example, instead of specifying it in the parameters of the `@Resource` Annotation like:

```
@Resource(format=['json', 'xml'])
class Book {

   String name

}
```

Can you specify it in `config.groovy` with something like

```
grails.resource.format = ['json', 'xml']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the code for the grails-rest plugin (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-rest/src/main/groovy/grails/rest/Resource.groovy) and on line 47, it appears XML and JSON are hard-coded in that order.